# JDBC connection MSQL error "No suitable driver found"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql@localhost:3306:emp
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.jdbd.connection.ConnectionDemo.main(ConnectionDemo.java:13)
```

here is my code

```
package com.jdbd.connection;

import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{

            //1. get a connection to database

            Connection myconn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql@localhost:3306:emp","root","Dreamliner787");
            //2.create a statement
            Statement mystm =myconn.createStatement();
            //3. Execute sql query
            ResultSet myRs = mystm.executeQuery("select*from employee");
             //4. process the result set
            while(myRs.next()){
                System.out.println(myRs.getString("last")+ ","  + myRs.getString("first"));

            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i have the jar file in the library too. what am i doing wrong

Comment: Try this `jdbc:mysql@//localhost:3306/emp`

Comment: @bmarkham Still throws the same exception

Comment: Before your `Connection myconn` add this `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: How about `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emp`?

Comment: @Pshemo I was gunna ask what was the difference between that and mine - but then I looked closely haha. Yes, try what Pshemo says

Comment: @pshemo thank you and  class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver"); is it the driver manager ? and would it work same for all the other sql connections ?

Comment: @bmarkham That will throw `ClassNotFoundException`, and hasn't been required since 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is either because your URL is wrong, or the JDBC driver is missing.

A JDBC URL typically looks like this `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql`. I'm not sure why you have an `@` in there. But that probably is the problem.

You can pinpoint if the problem is in the classpath by loading the driver like this.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

EDIT :

The `Class.forName` isn't JDBC specific. It's simply loading the Driver class into the current class loader. Nothing related to databases there.

Prior to JDBC 4.0 you had to initialize the driver this way. I guess since this worked, you must be using a lesser version.

Comment: yes i added the class.forName (...) and now it works, is class.forName a driver manager ? can you please elaborate on this.. thank you

Comment: im using  Connector/J 5.0.8

Comment: @RajeshSitaula Why? That version is *ten years old.* Use a current one, please.

Comment: Using `Class.forName` still works, except with a JDBC 4.0+ driver it is no longer necessary.